# wordpress on facebook tabs

Tags: facebook, wordpress, https

I wish to use my existing WordPress application on Facebook tabs.

currently my WordPress site is running over HTTP without HTTPS support.
im using  a shared hosting server for that.

How can i use the same WordPress installation to serve the same content with a different format over HTTPS for Facebook tabs ?

Answer (score 0):

There are available facebook applications that enables you to use an iframe within your facebook tabs page. You will simply add the url of the site to its options. You just need to make sure that your websites layout width is 520px and its centered.

Comment: that i know , but as i understand the iframe source must be https right? well my site is currently only uses http , how can i make https://www.x.com serve the same content over https ?